# Devolver imagen y cadena de texto Django

Tags: python, django

Necesito devolver una imagen atravez de return Httpresponse junto con una cadena de texto relacionada con dicha imagen, como puedo hacer para devolver tanto la imagen como la cadena de texto en una sola respuesta:

por ejemplo:

```
def funcion(request):
      cadena="Este es el texto que quiero imprimir"
      img= open('imagen.jpg','rb')
      aqui iria la respuesta o return para devolver la cadena de texto y la img
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo buscas mostrar la imagen y el texto, si deseas usar HttpResponse o regresas la imagen o regresas el texto ya que para mostrar la imagen tendrías que definir el content-type como 'image/' y el texto requiere un content-type diferente. Si quieres ambos puedes convertir la imagen a base64 después de abrirla y agregarla a un contexto junto con el texto, seria algo así:

```
import base64

def funcion(request):
    cadena = "Este es el texto que quiero imprimir"
    imagen = None
    with open('imagen.jpg', "rb") as archivo_imagen:
        imagen = base64.b64encode(archivo_imagen.read()).decode('utf-8')

    context = {'imagen': imagen, 'texto': caden}

    return render(request, 'mi_template.html', context)
```

mi_template.html

```
{% if imagen %}
    <p>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ imagen }}">
    </p>
{% endif %}

<p>
    {{texto}}
</p>
```

Comment: hola disculpa, en el caso de la imagen esta no se visualiza solo aparece un icono imagen, en el caso del texto este tiene etiquetas html como <br> y se visualizan en el mensaje, como puedo solucionarlo?